# Jquery: onload change hrefs parameter values of multiple links

Tags: jquery

I need to replace a set of parameters. When I do it like below the second parameter (dir2) +++ of Link1 is not replaced (because in Link1 both dir2 has the same value) +++. How can I resolve this?

```js
var myArray = ["data/", "downloads/", "images/", "leftover/", "new2me/", "news/"];

$.each(myArray, function(key, value) {

  $('.submenu').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', ($(this).attr('href').replace("http://www.nu.nl/", "http://www.telegraaf.nl/").replace(value, 'latestdata/')));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a class="submenu" href="test.php?url1=http://www.nu.nl/&dir1=images/&url2=http://www.nu.nl/&dir2=images/" target="showme">Link1</a></li>
<li><a class="submenu" href="test.php?url1=http://www.nu.nl/&dir1=downloads/&url2=http://www.nu.nl/&dir2=new2me/" target="showme">Link2</a></li>
<li><a class="submenu" href="test.php?url1=http://www.nu.nl/&dir1=data/&url2=http://www.nu.nl/&dir2=leftover/" target="showme">Link3</a></li>
```

EDITS: see above text ...... between +++

Comment: check your question's snippet..its already working fine.

Comment: When running it on my website I still have problems to replace dir2 (only dir1 is being replaced).........replacing url1 and url2 are OK.

Could the amount of urls be a problem?

Comment: Edited my question.........got a problem with link1

Comment: see the amount of code you provided is working fine as there is no issue in this code may be because of some other code problem exists we need to see that..

Comment: This code still has an issue because it does not do what I want as a result......  

> What it should show for link1 is:

test.php?url1=http://www.telegraaf.nl/&dir1=latestdata/&url2=http://www.telegraaf.nl/&dir2=latestdata/[link]

>But the result of the code above is:
test.php?url1=http://www.telegraaf.nl/&dir1=latestdata/&url2=http://www.telegraaf.nl/&dir2=images/[link]

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myArray = ["data/", "downloads/", "images/", "leftover/", "new2me/", "news/"];
//alert(myArray[0]);
for(i=0;i <myArray.length;i++){
$.each(myArray, function(key, value) {
$('.submenu').each(function() {
$(this).attr('href', ($(this).attr('href').replace("http://www.nu.nl/", "http://www.telegraaf.nl/").replace(value, 'latestdata/')));
});
});
}
});
```